# Google Script: Adding results in a new adjacent cell

Tags: google-apps-script

In my Google Spreadsheet, I would like to add 7 days to dates that are in columns F. The results should appear in column G. How can I print the results of my function in the adjacent cell, in column G? 
Sorry if my question sound basic, I'm a very newbie. Here is my code:

```
function UpdateDates() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow
    //Get the dates from the cell and convert them into Milliseconds since 1970/01/01
    var First = new Date(ss.getRange('F4').getValue()).getTime();
    var Second = new Date(ss.getRange('F5').getValue()).getTime()
    var Third = new Date(ss.getRange('F6').getValue()).getTime();
    var dayInMs = 24*60*60*1000    //one day in Milliseconds
    //add sevendays to each date in milliseconds

    First = First + (7*dayInMs)
    Second += (7*dayInMs)
    Third += (7*dayInMs)

   //Convert Milliseconds to date use new Date(time in ms) and set Values of the cell
    ss.getRange('F4').setValue(new Date(First));
    ss.getRange('F5').setValue(new Date(Second));
    ss.getRange('F6').setValue(new Date(Third));

}
```

right now when i run the code, it replaces what is in column F

Comment: It should be very obvious why your script overwrites the contents of column F. It should be similarly obvious how to not overwrite column F, and instead write elsewhere. Lastly, note that there are days that are longer and shorter than exactly `86400` seconds. Your script fails to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function UpdateDates() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=sh.getRange(4,6,3,2);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var day=1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      vA[i][1]=new Date(vA[i][0].getFullYear(),vA[i][0].getMonth(),vA[i][0].getDate()+ 7);
      //vA[i][1]=new Date(new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf()+ (7 * day));
    }
    sh.insertColumnAfter(6);
    rg.setValues(vA);
}
```